# Stopping the shell script if any of the query gets failed

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix, sunos

Below is my shell script from which I am trying to invoke few hive SQL queries which is working fine.

```
#!/bin/bash

DATE_YEST_FORMAT1=`perl -e 'use POSIX qw(strftime); print strftime "%Y-%m-%d",localtime(time()- 3600*504);'`
echo $DATE_YEST_FORMAT1

hive -e "
        SELECT t1 [0] AS buyer_id
            ,t1 [1] AS item_id
            ,created_time
        FROM (
            SELECT split(ckey, '\\\\|') AS t1
                ,created_time
            FROM (
                SELECT CONCAT (
                        buyer_id
                        ,'|'
                        ,item_id
                        ) AS ckey
                    ,created_time
                FROM dw_checkout_trans
                WHERE to_date(from_unixtime(cast(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(created_time) AS BIGINT))) = '$DATE_YEST_FORMAT1' distribute BY ckey sort BY ckey
                    ,created_time DESC
                ) a
            WHERE rank(ckey) < 1
            ) X
        ORDER BY buyer_id
            ,created_time DESC;"

sleep 120

QUERY1=`hive -e "
set mapred.job.queue.name=hdmi-technology;
SELECT SUM(total_items_purchased), SUM(total_items_missingormismatch) from lip_data_quality where dt='$DATE_YEST_FORMAT2';"`
```

**Problem Statement:-**

If you see my first `hive -e` block after the `echo $DATE_YEST_FORMAT1`. Sometimes that query gets failed due to certain reasons. So currently what happens is that, if the `first Hive SQL query` gets failed, then it goes to `second Hive SQL query` after sleeping for `120 seconds`. And that is the thing I don't want. So Is there any way if the `first query` gets failed dues to any reasons, it should get `stopped automatically` at that point. And it should start running automatically from the starting again after few minutes(**should be configurable**)

**Update:-**

As suggested by `Stephen`.

I tried something like this-

```
#!/bin/bash

hive -e " blaah blaah;"

RET_VAL=$?
echo $RET_VAL
if [ $RET_VAL -ne 0]; then
echo "HiveQL failed due to certain reason" | mailx -s "LIP Query Failed" -r rj@host.com rj@host.com
exit(1)
```

I got something like this below as an error and I didn't got any email too. Anything wrong with my syntax and approach?

```
syntax error at line 152: `exit' unexpected
```

**Note:-**

Zero is success here if the Hive Query is executed successfully.

**Another Update after putting the space:-**
After making changes like below

```
#!/bin/bash

hive -e " blaah blaah;"

RET_VAL=$?
echo $RET_VAL
if [ $RET_VAL -ne 0 ]; then
echo "HiveQL failed due to certain reason for LIP" | mailx -s "LIP Query Failed" -r rj@host.com rj@host.com
fi
exit

hive -e 'Another SQL Query;'
```

I got something like below-

```
RET_VAL=0
+ echo 0
0
+ [ 0 -ne 0 ]
+ exit
```

Status code was `zero` as my first query was successful but my program exited after that and it didn't went to execute my second query? Why? I am missing something here for sure again.

Comment: Does the `hive` command make use of an exit status for success vs. failure?

Comment: Honestly I have no idea on that...!!!

Comment: You can `echo $?` to see the exit status, so run a `hive -e "blah blah"` that you know will succeed, followed *immediately* by `echo $?` (if you do anything else in between those two commands you'll lose the exit status from "hive") -- then run hive again in a way that you *know* will fail, and `echo $?` again.

Comment: Let me try that then... Thanks for the suggestion Stephen...!!

Comment: @TechGeeky try `exit` instead of `exit(1)`, also you are missing a `fi` before `exit`

Comment: @Stephen, I tried the way you suggested me... But I didn't got any email as soon as it got failed as I clearly mentioned in my if loop. And also I got something `exit unexpected`. Something wrong with my syntax? I updated my question with all the details. Any thoughts will be appreciated..

Comment: Add `-e` to the shebang, i.e. `#!/bin/bash -e`

Comment: @SiGanteng, what is `fi`. Can you provide an exact syntax, then I can understand more I guess..

Comment: @TechGeeky http://codepad.org/wUisomul look at the last two lines

Comment: The expression `hive -e "blah"; if [ $? -ne 0 ]; then stuff; fi` is more idiomatically expressed `if hive -e "blah"; then stuff; fi`. If there is no `else` block, you could even say `hive -e "blah" || stuff`; but the main point here is that the whole purpose of `if` is to run a command and examine its exit code.

Comment: @TechGeeky in case it wasn't obvious, `fi` is `if` spelled backwards and it's used to close an `if` statement. Similar for `esac`. Fortunately there is no `rof` or `elihw`. :-)

Comment: @SiGanteng, I tried your way and I got this error- RET_VAL=9
`lip_query.sh: test: ] missing` And I didn't got any email. Why? Something I missed?

Comment: You need a space before the closing square bracket. Better yet, use `if hive ...` as outlined in my previous comment.

Comment: Hi Triplee, I found very strange thing with the exit code. I updated my question. Can you take a look and let me know what's wrong?

Comment: My Bad, I figure that out. `fi` is reverse of `if` and exit was after the if loop. Need to learn the syntax I guess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless I'm misunderstanding the situation, it's very simple:

```
#!/bin/bash

DATE_YEST_FORMAT1=`perl -e 'use POSIX qw(strftime); print strftime "%Y-%m-%d",localtime(time()- 3600*504);'`
echo $DATE_YEST_FORMAT1

QUERY0="
        SELECT t1 [0] AS buyer_id
            ,t1 [1] AS item_id
            ,created_time
        FROM (
            SELECT split(ckey, '\\\\|') AS t1
                ,created_time
            FROM (
                SELECT CONCAT (
                        buyer_id
                        ,'|'
                        ,item_id
                        ) AS ckey
                    ,created_time
                FROM dw_checkout_trans
                WHERE to_date(from_unixtime(cast(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(created_time) AS BIGINT))) = '$DATE_YEST_FORMAT1' distribute BY ckey sort BY ckey
                    ,created_time DESC
                ) a
            WHERE rank(ckey) < 1
            ) X
        ORDER BY buyer_id
            ,created_time DESC;"

if hive -e "$QUERY0"
then
    sleep 120
    QUERY1=`hive -e "
    set mapred.job.queue.name=hdmi-technology;
    SELECT SUM(total_items_purchased), SUM(total_items_missingormismatch) from lip_data_quality where dt='$DATE_YEST_FORMAT2';"`
    # ...and whatever you do with $QUERY1...
fi
```

The string `$QUERY0` is for convenience, not necessity.  The key point is that you can test whether a command succeeded (returned status 0) with the `if` statement.  The `test` command (better known as `[`) is just a command that returns 0 when the tested condition is met, and 1 (non-zero) when it is not met.

So, the `if` statement runs the first `hive` query; if it passes (exit status 0), then (and only then) does it move on to the actions in the `then` clause.

I've resisted the temptation to reformat your SQL; suffice to say, it is not the layout I would use in my own code.

Comment: Thanks Jonathan for the detailed suggestion. Can you see my updated question and what wrong I am doing while sending the email if it got failed?

Comment: @TechGeeky: The `]` of the `[` command must be a separate argument; spacing matters in shell scripts.  Wrong: `if [ $RET_VAL -ne 0]; then`.  Right: `if [ $RET_VAL -ne 0 ]; then`.

Comment: That's what I was thinking firstly.. I have already re-ran my script again by putting the space. let's see how it goes. Thanks for the help...

Comment: Hi Jonathan, I saw very strange behavior, I updated my question with the details. Status code was `zero` as my first query was successful but my program exited after that and it didn't went to execute my second query? Why? I am missing something here for sure again.

Comment: My Bad, I figure that out. `fi` is reverse of `if` and exit was after the if loop.

Comment: Give or take the terminology, yes: that was the problem.  `fi` is the end marker for an `if` statement (it isn't a loop), and as you say, the exit was not in the scope of the `if ... fi` so it was executed unconditionally.

Answer (score 2):

You may also find useful setting the *exit immediately* option:

> ```
>      set  -e      Exit immediately if a simple command (see SHELL  GRAMMAR
>                   above) exits with a non-zero status.  The shell does not
>                   exit if the command that fails is part  of  the  command
>                   list  immediately  following  a  while or until keyword,
>                   part of the test in an if statement, part of a && or  ||
>                   list, or if the command's return value is being inverted
>                   via !.  A trap on ERR, if set, is  executed  before  the
>                   shell exits.
> ```

as in this example

```
#!/bin/bash

set -e
false
echo "Never reached"
```

Comment: What about If I need to notify myself about this failure, I updated my question with more detail. But somehow I am getting exception as `test: ] missing`. Any thoughts will be of great help..